# Identifying directory in readdir() in C

Tags: c

How to check whether ent.d->name is file or directory when calling readdir() in C where ent is of type struct dirent*.

Comment: I notice you have a [so] account. Programming questions go there. If for some reason you are unable to post there, for example due to a question ban, that's no reason to post programming questions here.

Answer (score 2):

That's what `S_ISREG()` and `S_ISDIR()` are for when used together with `stat(2)`. See its man page for details.

If you can live with not being completely POSIX compliant, you can use `DT_REG()` and `DT_DIR()` to check for directoryness versus regularness, respectively. This is mentioned in the man page for `readdir(3)`.

Comment: You probably want to use `lstat`, not `stat`. (Are you assuming the OP is asking about Linux?)

Comment: Why? That choice depends on whether you want to identify symlinks or follow them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In addition, the man page mentions both, and explains the difference between them. This answer, in and of itself, is hardly enough to write the entireity of the code anyway (and this answer was written while the question was still on SuperUser).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz As for assuming Linux: `readdir()` is POSIX.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I'm talking about your reference to manual pages.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to try calling opendir() on the d_name and seeing if it returns null:

```
int isDir(struct dirent *ent)
{
    if (ent && strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") && strcmp(ent->d_name, "..")) // don't include pwd and parent dir
    {
        DIR *isDir = opendir(ent->d_name);
        if (isDir)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should probably close the DIR at some point...

Comment: Assuming POSIX, readdir() already returns the information the OP is asking for, so opendir() is redundant at best and a penalty at worst.